# jQuery PreventDefault not stop execution

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I should paste code first

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(e){                                    
        $(".error").hide();
        var hasError = false;

        .... ....

        var captcha = $("#captchacode").val();
        if(captcha == '') {
            $("#captchacode").after('<span class="error">You forgot to enter security image.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        } else {

            $.post("/checkcaptcha.php",
                { captchac: captcha},
                    function(data){

                        if (data == "Invalid"){
                            $("#captchacode").after('<span class="error">Invalid security text. Please try again</span>');
                            hasError = true;
                            e.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
            );
        }


        if(hasError == false) {
            $(this).hide();
            $("#sendEmail li.buttons").append('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading" id="loading" />');

            $.post("/sendemail.php",
                { emailFrom: emailFromVal, name: name, message: messageVal },
                    function(data){
                        $("#sendEmail").slideUp("normal", function() {                 

                            $("#sendEmail").before('<h1>Success</h1><p>Your email was sent.</p>');                                          
                        });
                    }
                 );
        }

        return false;
    });                        
});
```

Everything is working. Email is being sent. I'm getting error message while putting invalid captcha value. Just after showing error message, it's going in next step and form is submitting. I need your suggestion to fix that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jQuery.post()` function is a shorthand for an AJAX call. AJAX calls are asynchronous, and work by passing callbacks that execute when the request completes. Calling `$.post()` **does not** stop the execution of the code until the request receives a response, because the whole point of AJAX is for that **not** to happen. This means that your `if(hasError == false)` line will execute *before* the `if (data == "Invalid")` part of your callback function.

If you want something to happen *after* the response from the AJAX call then you need to move it to the callback function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        $(".error").hide();
        var hasError = false,
            elem = this;

        ........

        var captcha = $("#captchacode").val();
        if (captcha == '') {
            $("#captchacode").after('<span class="error">You forgot to enter security image.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        } else {

            $.post("/checkcaptcha.php", {
                captchac: captcha
            },

            function (data) {

                if (data == "Invalid") {
                    $("#captchacode").after('<span class="error">Invalid security text. Please try again</span>');
                    hasError = true;
                    e.preventDefault();
                } else {
                    $(elem).hide();
                    $("#sendEmail li.buttons").append('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading" id="loading" />');

                    $.post("/sendemail.php", {
                        emailFrom: emailFromVal,
                        name: name,
                        message: messageVal
                    },

                    function (data) {
                        $("#sendEmail").slideUp("normal", function () {

                            $("#sendEmail").before('<h1>Success</h1><p>Your email was sent.</p>');
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```